# Making code update automatically each day

Tags: jquery, json

I have a site that slides though different kind of texts.
The site is getting data from JSON and displaying it on the slide. For each day there is a different kind of information to be displayed.

Here is an example from the namedays.json:

```
{
  "01-01": "",
  "01-02": "Svea",
  "01-03": "Alfred & Alfrida",
  "01-04": "Rut",
  "01-05": "Hanna & Hannele",
  "01-06": "Kasper & Melker & Baltsar",
  "01-07": "August & Augusta"
}
```

Here is an example from the Idrottsevent.json

```
"01-23": [
                              "Dagens match:<br />Linköping VC-KFUM Eskilstuna volley<br />15:00 Folkungahallen",
                              "Dagens match:<br />LHC-Frölunda HC<br />16:00 SAAB ARENA"
 ],


 "01-24": [
                              "Dagens match:<br />Linköpings VC-Hylte Halmstad<br />15:00 Linköpings sporthall"
 ]
```

As you can see the difference is that Name only have one string for each day and Idrottsevent have an array for each day.

This works perfectly, the slides works and it does update automatically with getting **Names**. However, for some reason it doesn't update automatically with **the Games (Idrottsevent.json)** I have to manually update the site so that the changes to Idrottsvent occur each day.

Here is the entire index code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Linköping</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/textmetrics.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        // General config
        slideTime: 15*1000,
        fadeTime: 3*1000,


        // Time
        timeUpdate: 60*1000,

        // Names
        nameDayUrl: 'namedays.json',
        nameUpdate : 60*1000,

        // Events
        eventUrl: 'Idrottsevent.json',
        eventUpdate : 1*1000,

        // Weather
        weatherUrl: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=58.41&lon=15.62&cnt=1&units=metric&appid=43d793dc2060f8f642d05787626d6844',
        weatherUpdate: 1800*1000
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    Nedanför finns rutan som ska visas på LEDn.<br />
    Rutan är 304 x 128 pixlar.<br />
    </p>

    <div id="container304">
        <div class="slide304">
            <div class="center">
                <div id="timeTicker"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide304">
            <div class="center">
                <div id="weatherTicker"></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="slide304">
            <div class="center">
                <div id="nameTicker"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide304">
            <div class="center">
                <div id="opinionTicker">Tyck till<br />vattentornet@linkoping.se</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="games"> </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Global data 
    var _names = {};
    var _events = {};
    var _games = {};
    var _eventIsRemoved = false;


    // Get all slides in the container.
    var _slides, _slideIndex, _oldKey;

    function initSlides() {
        _slides = $('.slide304');
        _slideIndex = 0;
    }

    function fadeOutSlide() {
        $(_slides[_slideIndex]).fadeTo(config.fadeTime, 0, function() {
            _slideIndex = (_slideIndex + 1) % _slides.length;   // Next slide.
            fadeInSlide();
        });
    }

    function getFontSizeForText(text, maxFontSize) {
        var safetyMargin = 1;   // Some texts overflow without this.
        var elContainer = $("#container304");
        var width = elContainer.width() - safetyMargin;
        var height = elContainer.height() - safetyMargin;
        var fontSize = maxFontSize;
        do { var m = measureText(text, --fontSize); }
        while ((m.width > width || m.height > height) && fontSize > 0);
        return fontSize;
    }

    function setFontSizeForCurrentSlide() {
        if (typeof _slides == 'undefined')
            return;
        var fontSizePx = getFontSizeForText($(_slides[_slideIndex]).html(), 100);
        $(_slides[_slideIndex]).css({ fontSize: fontSizePx });
    }

    function fadeInSlide() {
        setFontSizeForCurrentSlide();
        $(_slides[_slideIndex]).fadeTo(config.fadeTime, 1, function() {
            setTimeout(fadeOutSlide, config.slideTime);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Get events
        $.ajax({
            url: config.eventUrl,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                _oldKey = "12-31";
                _games = result;
              setGame1();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                _games = {};
            }
        });

        // Get days
        $.ajax({
            url: config.nameDayUrl,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                _names = result;
                setTickerTime();
                setWeather();
                setName();
                initSlides();
                fadeInSlide();
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                _names = {};
            }
        });
    });

    function setEvent() {
        // Find next closest event. NOTE: The events are defined in GMT.
        var d = getTimeForEvents();
        var nowDate = addMinutes(d, -d.getTimezoneOffset());    // Adjust for browser.

        var eventIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < _events.length; i++) {
            var ev = _events[i];
            if (typeof ev.visibleFrom != 'undefined') {
                var visibleFrom = new Date(ev.visibleFrom);
                var visibleTo   = new Date(ev.visibleTo);
                if (nowDate >= visibleFrom && nowDate <= visibleTo) {
                    eventIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Now either set new event and time, or remove the event slide if there is nothing to show.
        if (eventIndex != -1) {
            var ev = _events[eventIndex];
            var eventDate = new Date(ev.eventDate);
            var tte = timeToEvent(nowDate, eventDate);
            var tteHtml = _events[eventIndex].text + '<br />' + tte;
            $('#eventTicker').html(tteHtml);
            setFontSizeForCurrentSlide();
            setTimeout(setEvent, config.eventUpdate);
        }
        else 
        {
            if (_eventIsRemoved == false) {
                var x = $('#eventSlide').remove();
                _eventIsRemoved = true;
                initSlides();
            }
        }
    }

    function setName() {
        // Select name.
        var nowDate = getTimeForEvents();
        var mm = addZero(nowDate.getMonth() + 1);
        var d = addZero(nowDate.getDate());
        var key = mm + "-" + d;
        var name = (typeof _names[key] != "undefined") ? _names[key] : "";
        $('#nameTicker').html((name == '') ? '' : ('Grattis<br />' + name));
        setFontSizeForCurrentSlide();
        setTimeout(setName, config.nameUpdate);
    }


    function setGame1() {
        // Select game.

        var nowDate = getTimeForEvents();
        var mm = addZero(nowDate.getMonth() + 1);
        var d = addZero(nowDate.getDate());
        var key = mm + "-" + d;
        if(key != _oldKey){
            _oldKey = key;
            var game = (typeof _games[key] != "undefined") ? _games[key] : "";
            if(game.length > 0){
                $('.games').empty();
                for(i = 0; i < game.length; i++){
                    $('.games').append('<div class="slide304"><div class="center"><div id="gameTicker'+ i +'"></div></div></div>');
                }
                for(i = 0; i < game.length; i++){
                    $('#gameTicker' + i).html(game[i]);
                }
                setFontSizeForCurrentSlide();
                setTimeout(setGame1, config.eventUpdate);
            }
        }

    //$('#gameTicker1').html(game[i])
    //setFontSizeForCurrentSlide();
    //setTimeout(setGame1, config.eventUpdate);
    }

    function setTickerTime() {
        var months = [ "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "maj", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec" ];
        var days   = [ "Söndag", "Måndag", "Tisdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag", "Lördag" ];
        var nowDate = getTimeForEvents();
        var d = nowDate.getDate();
        var h = addZero(nowDate.getHours());
        var m = addZero(nowDate.getMinutes());
        var timeHtml = days[nowDate.getDay()] + " " + d + " " + months[nowDate.getMonth()] + "<br />" + h + ":" + m;
        $('#timeTicker').html(timeHtml);
        setFontSizeForCurrentSlide();
        setTimeout(setTickerTime, config.timeUpdate);
    }

    function setWeather() {
        var timeout = config.weatherUpdate;
        var temperature = 0;
        var isOk = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: config.weatherUrl,
            async: false,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                try { // Fail safe.
                    if (result.count > 0) {
                        var w = result.list[0];
                        temperature = Math.round(w.main.temp);
                        isOk = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (ex) {
                    isOk = false;
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                isOk = false;
                timeout = 60*1000;  // Try again a bit faster.
            }
        });

        if (isOk)
            $('#weatherTicker').html((temperature >= 0 ? "+" : "") + temperature + '°C');
        else 
            $('#weatherTicker').html('');
        setFontSizeForCurrentSlide();

        setTimeout(setWeather, timeout);
    }

    function timeToEvent(nowDate, eventDate) {
        var dms1 = nowDate.getTime();   // milliseconds from 1970-01-01
        var dms2 = eventDate.getTime(); // milliseconds from 1970-01-01
        var dms  = dms2 - dms1;
        var negative = dms < 0;
        var ds = Math.abs((dms / 1000) % 60);
        var dm = Math.abs((dms / 1000 / 60) % 60);
        var dh = Math.abs(dms / 1000 / 60 / 60);
        ds = addZero(parseInt(ds));
        dm = addZero(parseInt(dm));
        dh = addZero(parseInt(dh));
        return (negative ? "-" : "") + dh + ":" + dm + ":" + ds;
    }

    var _eventDateAddition = 0;
    var _eventStartDate = new Date("2015-11-17T00:00:00Z");
    function getTimeForEvents() {
/*      // Uncomment for a faster timer.
        _eventDateAddition += 30000000;
        var date = new Date(_eventStartDate.getTime() + _eventDateAddition);
        // console.log(date);
        return date;
*/
        return new Date();
    }

    function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
        return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
    }

    function addZero(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```